# SharePoint Approval Workflow customizing email notifications

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

I am working in Sharepoint Designer on an approval workflow.  I am customizing the emails that are sent to the initiator and the approver.  How do I rebuild that link, so the approver can click the link right in the email and be routed to the infopath form the initiator filled out?  And how do I change name of the link (it currently says (no title))?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I use - hope it helps:

http://punaro.com/2012/01/derek/modifying-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-email/

[image: Define E-mail message screenshot]

> Click edit workflow > approval > Under “Customization” click Change the behavior of a single task > Under the “When a Task is Pending” section, find the line that says “then Email task notification to Current Task:Assigned To” and click the underlined link.
>
> The Define E-Mail Message window opens. Insert the highlighted text, select the text you wish to make a link, then click the Edit Hyperlink button.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is get the address of the form directly (yes, InfoPath forms work for this too), copy that, and insert it as a hyperlink into the e-mail formatter. For your second question, I would just imagine that you insert a hyperlink and set the description as the word you want with the address of the form, the same way as much of SharePoint handles hyperlinks.

Comment: Thanks Alex- in SP designer there is the ability to "look up" information from your forms, lists, and libraries.  Can i use this feature instead of copying the hyperlink? because i want the approver to see the form that the initiator filled out...not the original blank form.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, yes it makes sense. I went to check a workflow I already have that sends an email for approval on a form (and I am also using an InfoPath custom form). Here is the link I provide to the approver: [%CurrentTask:Form_URN%]. What this does is send them to the workflow approval screen with a link in it to the actual filled-out form. Hopefully this will be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I did this by using the "Add or Change" lookup button, but that doesn't format the hyperlink to name it what you want. It looks like you can get that, though, using the hyperlink button and then putting in the same lookup.